# Python 'del' raises AttributeError if called on mock on Python 3.6, but not on >=3.7

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I'm using `unittest.mock` to test my code. A function I've made adds an attribute to an object if it does not exists, using `hasattr`.

According to the documentation in [Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.mock.html#deleting-attributes) and [newer versions](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/unittest.mock.html#deleting-attributes), I could delete mock's attributes using `del`, but it fails on Python 3.6. On Python 3.7 and above, it works.

Here is a short test that shows what I'm trying to test:

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock

def add_attribute(info):
    if not hasattr(info, 'attribute'):
        info.attribute = 'Attribute Added'

def test_mock():
    info = Mock()
    assert hasattr(info, 'attribute')
    del info.attribute
    assert not hasattr(info, 'attribute')
    add_attribute(info)
    assert info.attribute == 'Attribute Added'
    del info.attribute
    assert not hasattr(info, 'attribute')
```

On python 3.8, it works:

```
======= test session starts ========
platform linux -- Python 3.8.5, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /code
plugins: cov-2.12.1
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                         

test.py .
```

On python 3.6, it fails:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.14, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /code
plugins: cov-2.12.1
collected 1 item                                                               

test.py F                                          [100%]

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
__________________________________ test_mock ___________________________________

    def test_mock():
        info = Mock()
        assert hasattr(info, 'attribute')
        del info.attribute
        assert not hasattr(info, 'attribute')
        add_attribute(info)
        assert info.attribute == 'Attribute Added'
>       del info.attribute

test.py:14: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <Mock id='140171347130128'>, name = 'attribute'

    def __delattr__(self, name):
        if name in _all_magics and name in type(self).__dict__:
            delattr(type(self), name)
            if name not in self.__dict__:
                # for magic methods that are still MagicProxy objects and
                # not set on the instance itself
                return
    
        if name in self.__dict__:
            object.__delattr__(self, name)
    
        obj = self._mock_children.get(name, _missing)
        if obj is _deleted:
>           raise AttributeError(name)
E           AttributeError: attribute

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/unittest/mock.py:728: AttributeError
=========================== short test summary info ============================
FAILED test.py::test_mock - AttributeError: attribute
============================== 1 failed in 0.11s ===============================
test_python exited with code 1
```

I'm not sure if the unittest library was updated, or maybe it's (un)expected behavior on how objects are passed around functions between Python versions.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in [222d303](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/222d303ade8aadf0adcae5190fac603bdcafe3f0) for issue [bpo-20239](https://bugs.python.org/issue20239)

This was backported to 3.7 in [d358a8c](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/d358a8cda75446a8e0b5d99149f709395d5eae19) which first appeared in [python 3.7.3rc1](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/changelog.html#python-3-7-3-release-candidate-1)

this patch makes a critical change to the `__delattr__` method on mocks

~excerpt of the <3.7.3 code:

```
    def __delattr__(self, name):
        # ...

        if name in self.__dict__:
            object.__delattr__(self, name)

        obj = self._mock_children.get(name, _missing)
        if obj is _deleted:
            raise AttributeError(name)
```

and compare that against the 3.7.3+ code:

```
    def __delattr__(self, name):
        # ...

        obj = self._mock_children.get(name, _missing)
        if name in self.__dict__:
            _safe_super(NonCallableMock, self).__delattr__(name)
        elif obj is _deleted:
            raise AttributeError(name)
```

in cases with repeated deletion, the 3.6 code would trigger the `AttributeError` (due to the first deletion setting `_deleted`) -- but the fix made it so that this would be avoided (via `elif`)